# How to make 'expected value line' in linear regression in r

Tags: r, linear-regression

Let's say that my 
I want to check linear regression assumption (exogenity of random variables) that E(epsilon)=0 and E(epsilon|X)=0. 
I already calculated E(epsilon)=mean(residuals) and it was almost 0 so this assumption is satisfied. 
I have now problem with the second assumption, i did write

```
plot(X,residuals(model),abline(a=0,b=0))
```

by this line created by abline is not so good in my opinion, I would rather use the same line as we can see for example in plot(model,1) (the red line - line of expectation).

I think it's better because I can be more sure about this conditional expectation.

Is there any possibility to make such in my plot above ?

Comment: Please give some example data, so we can run your example output.

Comment: Sure, lets take for example 

set.seed(101)

x=runif(100)

y=rnorm(100)+x

lmfit=lm(y~x)

plot(x,residuals(lmfit),abline(a=0,b=0))

Comment: I want to create mean line of point on the plots (now I have only stiltedly created line by function abline)

Comment: Hmmm, i was looking more about red line in commnad plot(lmfit,1). As you can see it's a line of expectation which is not constant, it changes among the x.

Comment: So why can't you use `plot(lmfit,1)`? I'm sorry, I simply don't understand what you are trying to plot.